# Create a named zone file for all domains

Tags: linux, dns

Is there any way to create a zone file for all domains. So when the nameservers are changed on a domain and pointed to my DNS server it has a default A record pointing to a holding page.

I'm not sure if this is even possible however it would be very useful for something I am working on.

I've explained it as best I can but if for whatever reason it does not make sense let me know.

Thanks in advance.